# How do I get netbeans to stop reporting "; expected" whenever I take my cursor off an unfinished line of code?

Tags: netbeans

This behavior is very annoying. I have combed through the options and can not seem to find this particular one. Anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Tools`->`Options`->`Editor`->`Hints`. Select your language like `JavaScript` from Language drop down and look for `Missing Semicolon` check-box and uncheck it.